# Extracting content within[] embedded inside curly brackets using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in the following format

```
test_str = '{"keywords": {"Associate Director Information Technology Services": ["Director of Technology Services"]}}'
```

My Regex code below

```
import re
matches= re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}',test_str)
```

gives the output

```
['"keywords": {"Associate Director  Information Technology Services": ["Director of Technology Services"]']
```

What change should I do in my Regex expression to output only

```
"Director of Technology Services"
```

Comment: looks like you have json data....use the `json` module

Comment: What things you actually want? bcz JSON module is so easy to manage and work with.

Comment: @AstikGabani I understand, but my file format is not exactly a json. It is a log file in .txt format. The .txt file contains many other info and also has strings of format `{"keywords": {"Associate Director Information Technology Services": ["Director of Technology Services"]}}`

Comment: You can convert string to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", test_str)

print(re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", test_str)[0])
```

instead of escaping `{` and `}` you should escape `[` and `]`. 
Alternative Solution using capturing of groups.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\[(.*?)\]")
test_str = '{"keywords": {"Associate Director Information Technology Services": ["Director of Technology Services"]}}'

print(regex.search(test_str).group(1))
```

### Output:

```
"Director of Technology Services"
```

Comment: Thank you @vishal. your findall solution is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code:

```
import json
test_str = '{"keywords": {"Associate Director Information Technology Services": ["Director of Technology Services"]}}'
test_str_json = json.loads(test_str)
output = test_str_json["keywords"]["Associate Director Information Technology Services"][0]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
Director of Technology Services
```